# Aternative code for min-width to work on Safari Browser

Tags: html, ios, css, laravel, safari

so I got this navigation

```
   <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
             <li>{{ HTML::clever_link("index", 'HOME' ) }}</li>
                <li>{{ HTML::clever_link("breeder", 'BREEDER PROFILE' ) }}</li>
                    <li>{{ HTML::clever_link("gallery", 'GALLERY' ) }}</li>
                        <li>{{ HTML::clever_link("contact", 'CONTACT US' ) }}</li>
                            <li>{{ HTML::clever_link("ecom", 'eCOMMERCE' ) }}</li>  
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and this css for `min-width`:

```
#cssmenu { 
  width: 767px; 
}
```

The `min-width` CSS Property works on firefox and chrome, but the problem is on safari, any alternatives? thanks

Comment: Since this clearly is an CSS issue, please post the html code that this view produces and then remove the [laravel] tag

Comment: There's no any issue with min-width in safari... you need to show us what the problem exactly is...

Comment: the ecommerce link goes down to a new line, underneath the home link

Comment: I don't see a min-width in your code?